# Apply filter on main sheet that is then applied to a set of other sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created a google spreadsheet that enables teachers to filter English outcomes for any particular assignment and rate them from on a scale of 1 to 5.  Issue is that if I have up to 30 students in any given grade nine English class, so I would need to apply the filter 30 times as each student has a unique sheet.  In grade 9 English for my province their are 116 outcomes in 5 different categories.
I would like to apply the filter on the 'Template/Master' sheet and use app script to then apply the same parameters to the other students. Or create a function that pops up a filter that is then applied to all student sheets.
What I have tried -

1. Create a macro of filtered event and apply it manually. I can do it, but teachers not so much.
2. Filtered template sheet, copied results to temp sheet, grabbed filtered outcomes, names of students and assignment into a Google Form (works great to enter data).

Issue here is how to get those answers back to the student sheet in the correct row of the outcome especially since the filter isn't applied to student sheet just the template sheet.
So after all of that work, I have circled back to what if I could apply a filter (unique for every assignment) to one sheet (template) and then have it applied to every student.

Code below was a recorded macro on my template page. Each filter would be unique to the assignment. Applied first filter to 'code' ie GO2, then checked outcomes I wanted.

```
function filterTest() {  
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
.setHiddenValues(['GO2', 'GO3', 'GO4', 'GO5'])
.build();

  spreadsheet
.getActiveSheet()
.getFilter()
.setColumnFilterCriteria(spreadsheet.getActiveRange()
.getColumn(), criteria);
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
.setHiddenValues(['1. use language to develop and clarify 
 thoughts and feelings', '2. respond sensitively to the ideas, 
  opinions, and interpretations of others', '4. express and 
  support 
  own ideas and opinions in increasingly formal situations 
  [such as 
 interviews, meetings, reports…]', '7. reflect on personal 
 language use to set language learning goals', '9. ask 
 extending 
  questions'])
 .build();
 spreadsheet
.getActiveSheet()
.getFilter()
.setColumnFilterCriteria(spreadsheet.getActiveRange()
.getColumn(), criteria);
 };
```

What I would like is to know if filtering every sheet is possible? (Googled my brains out)
Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: I would not use  filters.

Comment: Would it be possible to share an anonimized version of the spreadsheet?

Comment: Here is the link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15NPPjIO99fVXyPH0UsfCpVqBPc-J8b47-5MjnJTMeLc/edit?usp=sharing